# MDX Sorting On Columns

Tags: mdx, pentaho

Hi,

I want to order the `PriceValues` field in the following query in Ascending Order

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      Union
      (
        {[PriceValues].[Grand Total]}
       ,[PriceValues].[Grand Total].Children
      )
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      Union
      (
        {[Offer].[Grand Total]}
       ,[Offer].[Grand Total].Children
      )
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Act_RenewDetails]
WHERE 
  {[Measures].[Revenue]};
```

Comment: ordered based on the [Measures].[Revenue] amount or the dimension ([Price Value]) value?  If the latter, please provide some sample data of those values...

Comment: Hi..,   I want to order the  ([Price Value]) values..Its values are     50  75  60  1.5  56  5  7  17  96  like dat coming in that able..  And my doubt is can i order "Dimensions" of "String" kind...                     Thanks..

Comment: Do you need the ordering to occur at query time?  Or would it also work to reconfigure your dimension in BIDS (or SSDT)?

Comment: ya..i want to order that at query time only..

Answer (score 1):

To order a measure in ascending numerical order:

`{ORDER({[PriceValues].[Grand Total],[PriceValues].[Grand Total].Children}, [Measures].[Revenue], BASC)} ON COLUMNS`

**Edit:** Or you can order alphabetically by the member names of a dimension:

`{ORDER({[PriceValues].[Grand Total],[PriceValues].[Grand Total].Children}, [PriceValues].CurrentMember.name, BASC)} ON COLUMNS`

(I think `.name` might be `.memberName` or even `.caption` - my memory is rusty.)

Comment: Hi Magnus,it is ordering only the Measure values..But i want to order that PricePoint field which is only a dimension..Any idea for that..                          Thanks..